# The manuscript Summa Logicae (William of Ockham)

Tags: reference-request, logic, math-history

The *Summa Logicae* (Latin, in English it's *the Sum of Logic*) is a textbook on logic by [William of Ockham](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_S5dFdpF6xm0/SuC3NlxHmwI/AAAAAAAAAj4/zGiXgFk3NK0/s400/William-of-Ockham-Moscarlop-GNU-free.png). There are articles about *the Summa Logicae* [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summa_logicae)  and [in Logicmuseum](http://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Summa_Logicae_%28Ockham%29).

It was published in Paris in 1488. There are different typed variants of this textbook, for example [here](http://individual.utoronto.ca/pking/articles/Ockham.Summa_logicae.pdf) (in English).

But I can't find any scans or photos of the original handmade manuscript or the original (first) edition. Do you know any links or libraries or museims, where I can find it?

Comment: *Summa* doesn't mean sum. It means 'the foremost/greatest things'. I can't help you find it, but I thought it relevant still.

Comment: The only image I've seen is here: http://www.olemiss.edu/courses/logic/ockham2.jpg

Comment: Note that the date in Wikipedia is 1323, and in the picture is 1341.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, thank you, it's also useful.

Comment: @Frank: It's not quite that simple. "*summa*" as an adjective means "foremost/greatest", but since "*logicae*" is in the genitive, "*summa*" is being used as a noun. As a noun it can mean, as you say, "the foremost/greatest things", but also has other meanings. [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_Logic) does translate the title as "Sum of Logic". I think a good analysis of the title is given [here](http://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Summa_Logicae_%28Ockham%29): ...

Comment: ... "The Latin word *Summa* is difficult to translate, and does not mean a mere summary of its subject, but rather a comprehensive handbook, or manual or compendium, intended to cover all the salient points of the subject, written authoritatively, and from a single point of view."

Comment: @joriki I will disagree with Wikipedia on this one.  Probably best to leave it in the original Latin.

Comment: *Summa* as a noun has the extended meanings of "the completion [of something]," "the perfection [of something]" and of "the sum [of something]" or "the whole [of something]", see parts II.A and especially II.B.3 of the entry in Lewis and Short (http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsumma). In particular, cf. "summa cogitationum mearum omnium" in Cicero in the sense of something like "the summation of all my thoughts." I do think this is the general sense of *Summa* in "Summa logicae."

Comment: Cf. also the title of Aquinas' *Summa theologiae*, which Ockham must surely have known of, whose title is often (and pretty much correctly, I think) translated as "Summary of theology."

Comment: @Frank: The quote wasn't from Wikipedia, only the title.

Answer (score 2):

According to WorldCat, the 1323 manuscript of the Summa Logicae is held at the Vatican Library, whilst a [microfilm](http://libcat.slu.edu/search/?searchscope=3&searchtype=o&searcharg=65222222) of that manuscript is held by the Saint Louis University library system; WorldCat doesn't bring up anything else for the 1323 manuscript (though Saint Louis University also seems to have microfilms of a number of other 14th century manuscripts of the Summa Logicae), and no facsimiles of the 1488 editio princeps (held at the Bavarian State Library, according to WorldCat).

Comment: thank you very much. I connected with the Vatican Library and was given the material for my research.